# Does Marriage related divination exist in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, islamic-basis

In India some Muslim people goto a person and inquire whether their marriage will work out properly or not. Its called Faal Nikalna (somewhat similar to astrology).

Does this practice have any legitimacy in Islam ???

Comment: What is 'faal'?

Answer (score 1):

Believing Fortunetellers and Astrologers is major sin number 46 in [Imam Shamsu ed-Deen Dhahabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Dhahabi), *Al-Kaba'ir* (translated) or *Major Sins* in English ([pdf](http://www.khilafahbooks.com/wp-content/ebook-download/english/tazkiyyah/Major_Sins_khilafahbooks_com.pdf)).  Among other ayat and ahadith listed, we have:

> [He is] Knower of the unseen, and He does not disclose His [knowledge of the] unseen to anyone -- [Qur'an 72:26](https://quran.com/72/26)

Instead, Muslims ask Allah for guidance through [istikhara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salat_al-Istikharah):

> Salat al-Istikharah is a prayer recited by Muslims when in need of guidance on an issue in their life.